RDP Black Screen with White Cursor on 24.04LTS
I know this issue has been discussed before, but I couldn’t find a solution for my situation. When I try to use RDP to connect to my Ubuntu physical machine via the MS client, I’m presented with a black screen and a white cursor that I can move around. I’ve enabled ‘Remote Desktop’ and set the credentials. I don’t have xrdp running concurrently, and I’ve also tried logging out of the Ubuntu machine before accessing it with RDP. I’ve also tried matching the ‘screen’ resolution.
Ultimately, I’m trying to set up a headless physical Ubuntu machine and am having a lot of trouble. I’ve purchased dummy HDMI adapters for this purpose, but at this point, I can’t even RDP into the machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ubuntu Version: 24.04LTS
Remote System: Apple Silicon Sonoma 14.5 (I’ve tried multiple systems)
Client: Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.9.9 (2257)
Thank you

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user68186 the difference is the OP is correct, if one configures remote login and connects from say a mac then all one gets is a black screen and cursor
i have tried multiple different settings (for example if one does select login as admin the connect is refused).
this seems to be a bugged feature or requires some set of arcane rdpclient settings
the suggestions in the linked article do not work and installing x rdp defeats the purpose of the built in feature

In the new Microsoft RDP Client (now called Windows App), you need to change the settings in the RDP file.

Find the line that says: use redirection server name:i:0
Change it to: use redirection server name:i:1

If you can't find the RDP file, you can create a new one:

Right-click on your current connection.
Select "Export" to save the file.
Open the saved file and make the changes mentioned above.
Import the edited file as a new connection.

Shout out to: Reddit Answer from @JohnDoeMan79

Thank you. This fix worked for Microsoft Remote Desktop on Mac too, when connecting to Ubuntu 24.10 set up to use "Remote Login".

I just hit this issue.
After testing it seems to be caused by an incompatibility with the newer versions of the Microsoft RDP client.
Namely the Remote Desktop Client on windows and Mac and the new Windows App
If you use MSTSC.EXE on windows it will connect.
